# Retrieving key/ID values from app engine datastore?

Tags: python, database, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I've got a page on my Python app which has a drop-down box of locations associated with the current user, with the names of the locations as the visible values of the drop-down box. What I want to do is allow the user to select one of these locations to associate with their current location. When a user adds a new Location it is created as a child entity of that user, so I populate the drop-down box like this:

```
locinfo = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Location WHERE ANCESTOR IS :1", userinfo)
```

...and this is how I intend to display the drop-down box on the site (the i.key value is just a placeholder, I'll explain).

```
<select name="lockey">
    {% for i in locinfo %}
        <option value="{{i.key}}">{{i.locname}}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

So what I want to do is add a reference to one particular Location entity in a User record. In a normal relational database I would get the primary key of each location, print them out as the value of each option, and store them in the User record as a reference to the user's current location. However I've looked around and haven't found anything about retrieving the key, and the more I look around the more I get the impression I'm going about it the wrong way.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keys in the datastore are represented by objects, not simple values (see [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/keyclass.html))

For any entity in the datastore, call its `.key()` method to get its key object, and then you can get the printable representation by casting it to a string.

You can either set this up in your view code that gets data ready for the template, or if you want to be able to just call `i.key` in your template, you can create a read-only property in that model class.

Comment: The Django templates used by default in webapp are perfectly happy with `{{i.key}}`; this will call the `.key()` method of `i` and return the string representation.

Comment: Hmm. How about that -- looks like I've been doing extra work. Wonder what about the OP's code isn't working for him...

Comment: That worked for me - the problem was somewhere else in my code. However, I can't seem to save the user's current location in the Users table - I post the 'lockey' value to a page which assigns it to the user's current location (which is a db.Key() value) and it doesn't come up in the datastore viewer. When I try to get the value I get an error saying 'incomplete key'.